# jQuery knob i am trying to get solution for step value

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery knobs. In jQuery knob i am trying to get a solution for knob step value. I have a requirement for knob with min value 1 and max value 32. But in  the knob user can select only specific values i.e; `1,2,4,8,12,16,24,32`. User cannot select the other values. Can anyone help me in this regards.

**JS Code:**

```
<script> $( document ).ready(
  function() { console.log( "ready!" );
       $(".dial").knob({ 'change' : function (v) { } });
       $('.dial').trigger( 'configure', 
                           { "min":1, "max":32, "fgColor":"#FF0000", "skin":"tron", "cursor":true, "step":2 } );
       });
</script>
```

Comment: could you post the code you have tried, if possible create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $(".dial").knob({
        'change' : function (v) { 
   
  }
    });
  $('.dial').trigger(
        'configure',
        {
            "min":1,
            "max":32,
            "fgColor":"#FF0000",
            "skin":"tron",
            "cursor":true,
   "step":2
        }
    );
 });
</script>

Comment: its working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/cg8o60zq/

Comment: In the above script user can select all values from 1 to 32. I am looking for the solution that the user can select only 1,2,4,8,12,16,24,32.